# Turn date and time to just date

Tags: php, date, time

I need to change the following

```
13/07/2012T15:00:00
```

To

```
13-7-2012
```

I have tried to use `strtotime` as well as `date` but they did not work, and I am wondering why.

Comment: have you tried date('d-m-Y', $yourdate)?

Comment: @tcoder That won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime) to correctly parse this for you. That way, you don't have to do any manipulation to the original input, just feed it to [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/datetime.createfromformat), like so:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat( '!d/m/Y+', "13/07/2012T15:00:00", new DateTimeZone( "America/New_York"));
echo $date->format( 'd-n-Y');
```

This [will print](http://viper-7.com/EMZ8yh):

```
13-7-2012
```

Make sure you set the [correct timezone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) in the call to `new DateTimeZone( "...")`.

Comment: @AymanSafadi - PHP 5.3 was released on 2009-06-30, **[over 3 years ago](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Release_history)**. I think it's time to stop warning people about it.

Comment: I wish I could agree with you! At least GoDaddy [didn't support PHP 5.3 a year ago](http://support.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/php-5-3-or-bust/). Wouldn't surprise me if others still don't.

Comment: That's still **a year** ago... If your hosting company doesn't support 5.3 by now, they're garbage and they should be dropped.

Answer (score 1):

You're input string is not a [valid date format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) for [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime). Notably the `/` is not a recognized delimited for `dd/m/yyyy` format.

Simply converting the `/` to `-` solves the problem:

```
13-07-2012T15:00:00
```

Then you could do:

```
echo date('d-n-Y', strtotime('13-07-2012T15:00:00'));
```

To convert this string, you could do some simple string replacement.

```
str_replace('/', '-', $input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
date("d-n-Y", strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', "13/07/2012T15:00:00")) )
```

[Code at Work](http://codepad.org/fQWqJyuL)

Answer (score 0):

since you just need to get the   `13-7-2012` date you perform a replace of '/' in '-' to get the date

```
date('d-n-Y', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', '13/07/2012T15:00:00'));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can easily do that like this

```
$today = date("m.d.y");
```

For more details use these reference

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php